# Unable to correctly combine Group by and Order by in a join

Tags: mysql

I have a message table -

```
msg
_____
id                  int(11)
subject             varchar(255)
content             text
create_time         datetime
parent              int(11)
```

- `parent` is a foreign key onto the `msg` table itself.
- `parent` can only refer to a row which has `parent` set to `NULL` i.e. all replies inside a *conversation* have a single parent: the first message of the conversation.

I want to be able to select **parent** messages in descending order of `create_time`, taking  into account also the `create_time` of their replies, like the order of grouped conversations in Gmail. I also want to join the most recent reply (if one exists) to each parent.

I'm unable to come up with the right SQL. This is what I've done so far -

```sql
SELECT * FROM `msg` `parent`
LEFT JOIN `msg` `reply`
ON `reply`.`parent` = `parent`.`id`
WHERE `parent`.`parent` IS NULL
GROUP BY `parent`.`id`
ORDER BY `reply`.`create_time` DESC
```

Two immediate problems with this are -

1. Parent create time isn't taken into the `ORDER BY` clause.
2. This is not giving me the least recent reply for a parent.

I'd appreciate a poke in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207711/selecting-the-latest-per-group-of-items

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY `reply`.`create_time` DESC, `parent`.`create_time` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```sql
SELECT  `parent`.`id` AS `pId`
    ,   `parent`.`create_time` AS `pTime`
    ,   `parent`.`subject`
    ,   `parent`.`content` AS `pContent`
    ,   `reply`.`id` AS `rId`
    ,   `reply`.`create_time` AS `rTime`
    ,   `reply`.`content` AS `rContent`
    ,   IF(`reply`.`create_time` IS NULL, `parent`.`create_time`, `reply`.`create_time`) AS `max_time`
FROM    `msg` `parent`
        LEFT JOIN
        `msg` `reply`
        ON `reply`.`parent` = `parent`.`id`
WHERE   `parent`.`parent` IS NULL
ORDER BY `max_time` DESC
```